# Where can I get libsvn_client-1.lib for php build

Tags: build, static-libraries, php-extension

I've been trying to compile php using this tutorial: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs#pecl_extensions

I have 0 experience doing this.  I need to do it this way to get the very poorly supported php-svn extension.  After running the configure command a readout shows that I don't have libsvn_client-1.lib, and I have no idea where to get it.  I have looked here: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs#extensions_and_their_libraries and have googled my face off to no avail.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Found the library here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/ ...now I need another one, however, which doesn't seem to be inlcuded in the dev package: libsvn_ra_dav-1.lib

Comment: I can't find the .lib file. Only the .dll. Is this is the same file renamed?

Comment: Ah never mind found it. I'm trying to do the same thing - Compile php with php_svn. I need the same file now: libsvn_ra_dav-1.lib. Did you have any luck finding it?